# Multiple HDDs hanging constantly

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid, raid-1

I have an AMD Windows 7 system which has its OS on an SSD, and until previously had a single 4TB HDD as a data drive. I never had an issue with that drive until I installed a second 4TB drive and put the two of them in RAID 1 (using Windows disk manager)

After I finished reloading my data to the array, I noticed the array would hang randomly and often when accessing the data on it. I decided to use the "break mirror" function in drive manager to see if this was happening on only one of the drives, but once it was broken both drives are now independently having the same issue. I've tried removing one of the drives, but still had the issue with the remaining one.

I've looked quite a bit for someone else having the same issue, but haven't seen it. Does anyone have a clue what could be the cause of the issues im having?

*Other info: Drives are connected to the motherboard, Pagefile is limited to 4GB and is on my SSD, Indexing disabled on drives, x64 Win 7 with updates installed*

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please go into a little more detail as to what happens when the array hangs randomly. Also, please post any relevant entries that are logged in Windows Event Log when this occurs.

Comment: Thanks! Basically it stops reading for about 30 seconds than resumes, so if I was watching a video VLC would stop responding until it begins reading again. At this time I can't browse directories on the disk. Haven't thought to look at logs, I'll check this out when I get home.

Comment: Have you tried running [chkdsk /f](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872425.aspx)  ?  Since you had Windows create and handle the mirrored set then the drives should be formatted as Windows Dynamic disks. If chkdsk doesn't help you can converting one of the HDDs back to a basic disk, that will delete all the data, try copying the data back and see if the issue will persist.